# How to get values about change points in facebook prophet?

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I used to Facebook Prophet library, now I have a problem.
When I use add_changepoints_to_plot function, I can see red lind and red dots line about change points, but I want to get this values.
How to get a values about change points or incline?

I wanna get numerical values of moments or values of time about change points. And I need way to decision whether the trend goes up or down through values.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome SO. You need to provide some code snippet.

Prophet need a data frame which contains two columns (ds and y). 
While column ds contains dates, column y contains value of the date.
As far as i understand, your data have changepoints and `you want to see the values on changepoint dates`

I'll leave an example code snippet here assuming you have a df with column "ds" and "y":

```
estimator = Prophet()
estimator.fit(df)
df.loc[df["ds"].isin(estimator.changepoints)]
```

`estimator.changepoints` contains the dates which occur changepoints. If you filter these dates from your dataframe you will get changepoint values.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
mdl = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True, interval_width=0.95, n_changepoints = 5)
mdl.add_country_holidays(country_name='US')
mdl.fit(df)
mdl.changepoints
```

Output:

62    2021-07-06

125   2021-09-07

187   2021-11-08

250   2022-01-10

312   2022-03-13
Name: ds, dtype: datetime64[ns]